# Nested 'for' loop overwriting data

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, nested-loops

```
COMMON_CASES = {'OSX Catalina - Latest Chrome': {'acceptSslCerts': 'true',
                                  'browser': 'Chrome',
                                  'browser_version': '81.0 beta',
                                  'browserstack.debug': 'true',
                                  'browserstack.local': 'true',
                                  'browserstack.networkLogs': 'true',
                                  'os': 'OS X',
                                  'os_version': 'Catalina',
                                  'resolution': '1280x1024'},
 'OSX Catalina - Latest Edge': {'acceptSslCerts': 'true',
                                'browser': 'Edge',
                                'browser_version': '81.0 beta',
                                'browserstack.debug': 'true',
                                'browserstack.local': 'true',
                                'browserstack.networkLogs': 'true',
                                'os': 'OS X',
                                'os_version': 'Catalina',
                                'resolution': '1280x1024'},
 'OSX Catalina Latest Safari': {'acceptSslCerts': 'true',
                                'browser': 'Safari',
                                'browser_version': '13',
                                'browserstack.debug': 'true',
                                'browserstack.local': 'true',
                                'browserstack.networkLogs': 'true',
                                'os': 'OS X',
                                'os_version': 'Catalina',
                                'resolution': '1280x1024'}}

LOGIN_SUCCESS = {'Login Success Customer': ('vedran@fishing.vedran', 'vedran123'), 'Login Success Captain': ('vedran@fishing.vedran', 'vedran123'), 'Login Success Admin': ('vedran@fishing.vedran', 'vedran123')}

caps = []
for case_index, (test_name, test_data) in enumerate(LOGIN_SUCCESS.items()):
    for test_index, (case_name, device_data) in enumerate(COMMON_CASES.items()):
        # case_s = f'{case_name} / {test_name}'
        device_data['name'] = test_name
        caps.append(test_data + (device_data,))

print(caps)
```

I have two variables that I need to merge using two for loops because I need to build a name for the test case using the keys from both arrays. I have 3 items in both dicts, so I need to have 9 items in the final list, which should be a list of tuples.

Now, when I run this, I expect the that the list will contain 3 of each Login cases, **Login Success Customer, Login Success Captain and Login Success Admin**
But, if you run the code that I provided, you will see that the 'name' in the dict is always **Login Success Admin**. How is that? When I print the code inside the function, everything is correct, but when I append to the list, it somehow changes. Do nested loops work differently in Python?

Comment: Please put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: You can see it now.

Comment: That's not really minimal, but: your `caps` list contains multiple references to *the same dictionary*. You never make any copies of the dictionaries from `COMMON_CASES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python are passed by reference, so this line in your code:

```
device_data['name'] = test_name
```

changes the dictionaries in the original COMMON_CASES variable, so when the loops end, the values of the 'name' fields will be set to the 'name' value from the last 'case' iteration ('Login Success Admin').

You can make a copy of the dictionary:

```
caps = []
for case_index, (test_name, test_data) in enumerate(LOGIN_SUCCESS.items()):
    for test_index, (case_name, device_data) in enumerate(COMMON_CASES.items()):
        device_data2 = device_data.copy()
        device_data2['name'] = test_name
        caps.append(test_data + (device_data2,))
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of the data you need and use that instead

```py
caps = []
for case_index, (test_name, test_data) in enumerate(LOGIN_SUCCESS.items()):
    for test_index, (case_name, device_data) in enumerate(COMMON_CASES.items()):
        data = device_data.copy()
        data['name'] = test_name
        caps.append(test_data + (data,))
```

As jonrsharpe mentioned in his comment, you are referencing the same dictionary. Python does not implicitly make copies of a dictionary when you assign them to a new variable. They point to the same memory location.